# MariaDB General Log Not Working

Tags: mariadb

I'm having trouble enabling local query logging for MariaDB. In the `C:\WAMP\MariaDB\data\my.ini` file I have the following:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=C:/WAMP/MariaDB/data
port=3306
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2014M
character-set-server=utf8
general_log = 1
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log = 1
log = "C:/WAMP/MariaDB/logs/queries.log"
```

However no matter what I do the `log` key prevents MariaDB from starting. I've moved it around to different parts of the config file and it has no effect, a site that very clearly uses a database and would generate queries should be updating that file though wasn't.

In short, without mentioning the former MariaDB is based upon, *how do I enable general query logging for MariaDB?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to minimize the working code to the following (last two lines):

```
[mysqld]
datadir=C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/WAMP/MariaDB/data
port=3306
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2014M
character-set-server=utf8
general-log
general-log-file=C:/WAMP/MariaDB/logs/queries.log
```

Answer (score 2):

The `log` option was deprecated in 5.x releases and removed in 10.0. Apparently you are running a 10.x version of the server. 
To set the path/name of the general log, you need to use [`general_log_file` option](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#general_log_file) instead.

Or, if you are trying to set the location of the *error* log, then the option name is [`log_error`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#log_error).

Comment: A great resource, I was doing a lot of searching and never came across that page. I posted a working answer but still up-voting this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is documented here: [General Query Log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/general-query-log/)

> The general query log is disabled by default. Since it's a record of
>   every query received by the server, it can grow large quite quickly.
>   If you only want a record of queries that change data, rather use the
>   binary log instead.

Example of how to log to file:

By adding this to your my.cnf file all queries will be logged to the file queries.log in the `datadir` directory.

```
[mariadb]
log_output=FILE
general_log
general_log_file=queries.log
```

Comment: Hmm on the documentation page, it says the command is "general_log" not "general-log"... maybe this changed since you wrote this answer?

Comment: Strangely, it's working for me with dashes, actually. My guess is that they either changed it at some point in the past, and/or it's always worked with either (just to make life easier for us devs!).

Comment: @Eric this is indeed a feature `Within option names, dash (-) and underscore (_) may be used interchangeably. For example, --skip-grant-tables and --skip_grant_tables are equivalent. (However, the leading dashes cannot be given as underscores.)` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/command-line-options.html

Comment: Oh, that's great. Interestingly these aren't options on the command line, they're in a config file... but I realize, kinda the same thing. In any case, I think it's *very* smart of the devs to allow dash or underscore to work. It's being flexible with these kinds of little fussy details that makes software a pleasure to use.